# Validating username and password in a database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a login page. I have a database table called Login, and it has two columns: ID and Password. It has the following ID and Password pairs in it: First row:(13282,123456), Second Row:(11111,11111). If username and password is right, i redirect page to succesful.aspx, if either username or password is wrong, i redirect page to unsuccesful.aspx. My problem is, When i enter 13283 as ID and 123456 as password, it does everything right, i am redirected to succesful page. But when i enter ID=11111 and Password=11111 even though everything is true, it redirects to unsuccesful page. I think the problem is, my query only checks the first row. Here is the code:

```
 protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=University;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";


    Int32 verify;
    string query1 = "Select count(*) from Login where ID='" + idBox.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordBox.Text + "' ";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    con.Open();
    verify = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    con.Close();
    if (verify > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("succesful.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("unsuccesful.aspx",true);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Don't concat strings to build your query. I personally like the password '; delete from Login; Use parameterized queries instead. 2) Salt the password and then hash it. Never store plaintext passwords.

Comment: It's also a good idea to trim spaces from usernames and passwords (eg username.Trim()).  Often users copy/paste usernames and passwords and it is not evident they copied a trailing space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are wrong with this approach:

- **It requires storing passwords in plain text** - This is the worst thing one can do to a user's password: anyone who accidentally gains access to your database would instantly be in possession of all your users' passwords, with is very, very bad.
- **It is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks** - Concatenating strings to produce a SQL command is dangerous, because malicious users could enter strings that break your SQL and turn it into [something else](http://xkcd.com/327/).

You should study the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/335858). The approaches discussed there are not nearly as simple as what you are implementing, but they make your system a lot more bullet-proof.

Comment: Thanks, but actually this is my first try in connecting to a database and checking the username-password pairs. I am just trying to achieve this right now :) and security is not important for now. Any suggestions about how to do this? Or any source explaining the login page and user validation?

Comment: @bigO The only reason I could think of why your query does not work is that the data types of `ID` and `Password` are wrong (e.g. `char` instead of `varchar`). The two major concerns aside, the query should work.

Comment: Oh, thank you when i changed data types to varchar it worked. What was the problem before, what is the difference between char and varchar?

Comment: @bigO char is fixed-length, while varchar is variable length. When you insert char that has fewer characters than declared length, DB pads it to fixed length for you; when you insert varchar, DB stores the exact string.